# Who is still alive from the original series?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

We know for certain that Katara is still around from the original series, since she shows up in the first episode. We also know that Aang is dead, since Korra would have been born at the moment of his death. Who else is still alive? Who's known to be dead?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The easiest way to tackle this question is to [list characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avatar:_The_Last_Airbender#Characters) and their current known status:

- **Aang** *Dead, confirmed*
- **Katara** *Alive, confirmed*
- **Sokka** *Dead, confirmed* : in *[Welcome to Republic City](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Transcript:Welcome_to_Republic_City)*, Katara says :

  > Aang's time has passed. My brother, and many of my friends are gone.
- **Zuko** *Alive, confirmed* : from [The Legend of Korra: Welcome to Republic on nick.com](http://www.nick.com/games/legend-of-korra-welcome-to-republic-city.html?navid=showNav) , when you go in "Central City Station" and get the information about the Zuko statue, you learn that :

  > Three years ago, Zuko turned over the reins of the fire nation to his daughter. Officialy, he's retired, but unofficially, he still travels the world as an ambassador for world balance
- **Toph Beifong** *Alive, Confirmed* : She Is residing at the swamp.
- **Appa** *Unknown*
- **Momo** *Unknown*
- **Iroh** *residing in the spirit world*
- **Azula** *Unknown*
- **Suki** *Unknown*
- **Mai** *Unknown*
- **Ty Lee** Unknown
- **Ozai** *probably dead* : considering his age.

Comment: I don't know about Toph, she was the youngest of the Gaang - if she's dead, it probably wasn't of natural causes. Just because there's statues of you doesn't mean you're dead :)

Comment: @Tacroy Thats why I put *Unknown* as her status. Meanwhile, [her wiki](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Toph_Beifong#After_the_War) say she is death, but I don't think the reference they put conclusive because it just say "that whole generation has died". The key point is that Katara did survive and say "**many** of my friends are gone", which leave place to some other survival.

Comment: Zuko's alive. On Nick.com, it states that Zuko still travels though world, though he is retired. He has handed the Fire Nation over to his daughter.

Comment: @FirebenderGirl thanks, I found the quote and updated the answer.

Comment: Weellp, that looks like all the information we'll get out of the first season.

Comment: I can't find the article, but I distinctly remember the show's creators stating in an interview that Azula was indeed still alive.