# Who is still alive from the original Avatar in the Legend of Korra series?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Who is still alive from the original series?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15092/who-is-still-alive-from-the-original-series)

I actually have no idea who is still alive from the orginal series. The only one who I really see is Aang and some of the others in Korra's visions but who is actually in the series and is alive? Besides Katara.

Comment: I realize this too might be discouraging. I hope in seeing the care and completeness that our community takes in staying free of duplicates only serves to encourage you to ask new questions. I am sure there are great things to be asked in this space. I know that, at first, our community can seem cold and uninterested in what you have to say. It isn't, and you now have the reputation to join us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley), and I hope you do.

Comment: Also, is this your account? http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/8080/danielle we can have it merged (hopefully) and you'll have even more rep. Please join us in chat.

Comment: Yes that's my account just on a different laptop.

Comment: Instead of editing your post to ask another question, simply start a new question by clicking "Ask Question" in the top right corner :)